# page-break-inside for a printable page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My application should support all modern browsers. The minimum required IE version is IE9.

I have created a very basic page that can be printed. On the page, there's a table. Each row contains some information about an article, including a barcode.

When printing this page, the last row on the page is partially on one page, partially on the other. Worse, the barcode is split between two pages (the barcode is a number displayed in a special font).

I've had a look at `page-break-inside`. Here's my current code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
    <p class="text-center">Liste de prix</p>
        <table class="table borderless">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-xs-4">Description</th>
                    <th class="col-xs-2">Prix / tige</th>
                    <th class="col-xs-2">Taille</th>
                    <th class="col-xs-4">Code</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="article in vm.data.articles">
                    <div><td>{{ article.description }}</td></div>
                    <div><td>{{ article.unitPrice }}</td></div>
                    <div><td>{{ article.length }}</td></div>
                    <div><td style="font-family: barcode, arial; font-size: 225%;">{{ article.itemNumber | barcode }}</td></div>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

css: 

tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

(Don't mind the ugly inline style, that's just for testing purposes)

This does not do anything at all. I've had a look at similar questions and I've tried different solutions, like putting div's around the td's (that's why they're there) and using page-break-inside on these div's, using page-break-inside on the rows,... still, none of these solutions seem to do anything.

I've discussed this issue with a colleage and he thinks there's nothing I can do to actually make this work.

Is this true? Am I doing something impossible? If not, why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some css magic gives you the solution.

Like,

```
table tbody {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  top: /* your desired value.*/ 
}
```